# Updated Katalon Studio to version 5.9.1 - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, katalon-studio

After updating Katalon Studio to 5.9.1, we occasionally get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.elektLabs.Keywords` on our custom keyword class while running tests in Jenkins.

What is weird is that it doesn't happen every time and we are not able to reproduce it. It worked before in 5.7.

Here is beginning of our custom keyword class:

```
package cz.elektLabs
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element
import org.jsoup.select.Elements
import org.openqa.selenium.By

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import internal.GlobalVariable

class Keywords {
    @Keyword
    def boolean checkIfValidImage(String url) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And here is the error we get:

```
2018-12-14 09:18:53.987 ERROR k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - ? cz.elektLabs.Keywords
2018-12-14 09:18:53.988 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ? cz.elektLabs.Keywords.openAndLogin() FAILED.
Reason:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cz.elektLabs.Keywords
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.getCustomKeywordClassAndSetMetaClass(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:98)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:44)
    at TestSystem.run(TestSystem:17)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:321)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:312)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:291)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:283)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:222)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:129)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:112)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:149)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1544775530390.run(TempTestSuite1544775530390.groovy:36)
```

Is there anything we could do to fix this issue?

edit: We updated Katalon Studio to version 5.10.1 and we are still getting `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError` every now and then.

Comment: Do you have just one Jenkins machine? Maybe it's related to the agent executing the tests.

Comment: There is a [5.10.0 beta version](https://forum.katalon.com/t/katalon-studio-5-10-beta-release/15344) available. Try to see if this is reproducible there.

Comment: @Henry sorry for late answer, but yes, we have only one Jenkins machine, Windows x64 with Java version 8 update 151

Comment: @MateMrše We updated Katalon Studio to version 5.10.1 and the problem prevails.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have installed **Open JDK 1.8** on the machine.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. I will change this to comment when I have enough reputation point.